# Using LINQ to reference XML local Xelements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

All,
It's easy enough to do reference the **LocalName** of an **Element** when using a **foreach**.

However, if I'm interested in a particular element name, perhaps because each element has an array of children elements and I want a **LocalName** of a parental element, how do I go about it, without resorting to a pull of the **DefaultNamespace** or **Prefix**?

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> families = xelement.Elements();

foreach (var family in families)
{
  foreach (var member in family.Elements())
  {
    // easy to grab the LocalName
    var memberName = member.Name.LocalName;
    var memberValue = member.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("memberName = " + memberValue + ", memberValue = " + memberValue);
  }
  // This could fail because I didn't reference the Namespace
  var familyName = family.Element("familyName").Value;
}
```

(yes I could use an **if** within the **foreach** but that incurs overhead - small yes - but still overhead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have the option to create extension methods to find elements by local name. Whether you like it or not, you *have* to "use an if within the foreach," that's an ovherhead you'll have to accept.

This implementation is in terms of LINQ but you could always write it out by hand.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> LocalElements<T>(this T source, string name)
            where T : XContainer
    {
        return source.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> LocalDescendants<T>(this T source, string name)
            where T : XContainer
    {
        return source.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == name);
    }

    public static XElement LocalElement<T>(this T source, string name)
            where T : XContainer
    {
        return LocalElements(source, name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this to get the value:

```
var familyName = (string)family.LocalElement("familyName"); // always use casting
```

Comment: brilliant!  Thank you!  It is however unfortunate that even though solution isn't writing a loop, the IL is :(